# Need an online resource to help me style a web application

Tags: css, styling

I have a website that I put together and it's functional but it doesn't look nice.  I've assigned CSS classes and IDs to everything to make it easier to come back and add styles later, but I have NO skills when it comes to eye-pleasing colors and layouts.

There are many sites that offer free website templates, but they're all so specific that I can't seem to find one that will help me style my website.

Can anyone suggest a site that has simpler CSS examples?  I don't need a tutorial; I understand CSS, I just can't do "pretty".

Honestly, if my wife doesn't pick out my clothes, I look terrible... I need help with styling.

(Oh, and if stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask something like this, please direct me to the more appropriate place.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thus .. You want to learn how to **design** and choose colors?

To start, you can get some template inspiration at [CSS Drive](http://www.cssdrive.com/) and [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/). You can choose and combine "good colors" at [CSS color scheme designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/).

More hints can be found at Google using "[css design templates](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+design+templates)" and "[css color schemes](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+color+schemes)".

Comment: BalusC, I wish I could mark several "answers" because there was so much help offered here, but your response seems to be most along the lines of what I was looking for.
That CSS Zen Garden blew my mind.  I got some REALLY clever ideas from there, though they're beyond the scope of this current phase of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. You are talking about a web *application*, right? How about [**JQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/)? It would imply using JQuery on the UI end, too, so I don't know whether this is really helpful for you, but it brings a number of very nice-looking application templates, and pre-styled controls.

Comment: Pekka, I am using jQuery for the functionality already and was planning to use jQuery UI for many of the controls after I got the core functionality working, but I confess I hadn't looked that closely.  I thought it was mostly pretty components and didn't really have a site-wide theme concept.  If it does, then you've provided me the kick I needed to go ahead and start looking into it.

Comment: Check out the examples, there's quite a lot there already. It looks to me as if it's enough to build a whole app on, or very close to it - but you'll have to check out whether it suits you.

Answer (score 2):

There are some basic things you can do to make your design look less like a developer designed it :):

1. White Space! Lots of white space! If you think you've used too much white space, add just a little bit more. Minimum of 20-30px padding/margins between major interface elements.
2. Use different fonts other than the web safe defaults. Look in to using something like [Typekit](http://typekit.com/).
3. Read up on color theory. Don't stick to the overused blue, black and white color scheme.

There are plenty of tips we can give you here, but good design sense is built up over time. Some other resources you can check out are:

- http://smashingmagzine.com
- http://doctypetv.com

Comment: "Use different fonts" is a dangerous recommendation. Going crazy with fonts is one of the surest signs of an amateur (see also: *every newsletter ever*).

Comment: Very true. Limit yourself to 2 to 3 fonts at MOST for any given design. Be conservative with the ones you do choose. When I say use other fonts, basically look for an alternative to Helvetica.

Comment: Derek, neither of the "other resources" links you posted seem to go where you think they go.

Comment: I meant add that I will incorporate your enumerated points into my plans.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine if somebody said "I drew a Web application in my sketchbook. I need an online resource to help me program it. I'm really bad at programming." It sounds silly when it's applied to your discipline, doesn't it? But honestly, you can't just look at one resource and all of a sudden be a good designer any more than you could look at one resource and suddenly be a good programmer.

If this app is just for fun, sure, take the resources people have recommended (Zen Garden, etc.) and have a grand old time. But if this is meant to be a "serious" project, you should hire somebody who actually knows design. Go to school and learn design yourself if you want, but have enough respect for the craft to realize that it's not something you can teach yourself in seven days.

Comment: Well spoken, Chuck.  I certainly don't mean any disrespect to designers.  This is not going to be an app that I'm trying to put onto store shelves; I just want it to stop looking like ass.
So, I don't need a professional, I just need some color scheme assistance and some broad layout ideas.  Something I imagine a true designer would consider "novice".

Comment: The best advice on that subject I can give is look at free css templates on google, and get ideas. Its the ideas that count. And trust me when I tell you, you are WRONG about being a bad designer. I felt EXACTLY word-for-word the same way you did, until I quit convincing myself I suck and just did my research and practiced it. Sorry its not a short-term solution. (Edit: try it out, ask your wife/friends to critique it)

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise to hire a freelancer for this job.

Especially, if the functionality is already done and site is pursuing any kind of commercial success.